# Asymptotic estimate for sum of powers of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Let $k$ be a fixed positive number and let $n$ go to infinity. Then by Polya (Problems and Theorems in Analysis) it holds that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^t\simeq 2^{tn}\left(\frac{2}{\pi n}\right)^{\frac{t-1}{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2t}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

I read the proof, but I did not understand it. Can anyone give a detailed proof?

Thank you